# Can i implement one to one voice call(VOIP) in Flutter using agora_rtc?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, agora.io

Looking to make an app which supports one to one call (voice only) using [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/agora_rtc_engine).Where user can call to specific user I would like to know how to in flutter we can be able add this feature and to show a incoming call screen or push notification as there is no example in the their official documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine) that you shared then you can simply call `disableVideo()` function before joining the channel. You can clone this repo over [here](https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-videocall-demo) and replace `enableVideo()` with `disableAudio()` and you will have your 1 to 1 audio calling.

You can take a look at the get started guide here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/start_call_audio_flutter?platform=Flutter

Agora does not provide any API to send push notification. You can use [callKeep](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep) to push notification to a user with an incoming call screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But the agora_voice_engine package you mentioned is not released yet and disable video wont be charged as a video call?

Comment: Yes, the package isn't released on pub.dev yet but you can use the github code base itself. I actually dont know about the pricing you can just send your doubts related to pricing over here: https://www.agora.io/en/contact-sales/

Comment: link is broken https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK/tree/audio-only please update it or remove this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am implementing the same feature with callKeep plugin but this plugin is asking SIP account. I am not getting what should be URL for SIP Screen invoked by CallKeep

Comment: GitHUb link is not openiong